# Power BI Data set when sharing through Power BI Service

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-crm-365

I am using a Microsoft Dynamics 365 API to load data into my Power BI Report. This is done by the Power BI internal Dynamics 365 (Odata) connector. I connect to this Dynamics 365 service with my "Organizational Account" (Azure AD). When connected successfully, i take some entities and render them on my dashboard.

This Dashboard is published to Power BI Service which also runs under my account. This works fine as i can see my dashboard and dataset published successfully to the Power BI Sevice.

When i open it, no issues and i can see the data on the dashboard.

My question: When sharing this dashboard with others, will they see the data connected to the Dynamics 365 API using my credentials as provided in Power BI Desktop when connecting to D365? Or will they be asked to provide their credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the users will be able to see the insights created in the dashboard.

Please note the connecting to the data source is done using your credentials and at the same the data refresh has to happen accordingly